# How to implement room database with coroutines correctly?

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, android-room, kotlin-coroutines

I am developing news android and I already implemented database logic with room what I want to achieve I want fetch data first and then save to room database but  I have implemented that logic already when I run the application it is showing white screen only progress bar loading

below screenshot of android app

[image: screenshot of app]

below my MainViewmModel.kt class

```
class MainViewModel(val newsRepository: NewsRepository) : ViewModel(), CoroutineScope {
    // Coroutine's background job
    val job = Job()
    // Define default thread for Coroutine as Main and add job
    override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext = Dispatchers.Main + job

    val showLoading = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
    val sportList = MutableLiveData<List<Article>>()
    val showError = SingleLiveEvent<String>()

    fun loadNews() {
        // Show progressBar during the operation on the MAIN (default) thread
        showLoading.value = true
        // launch the Coroutine
        launch {
            // Switching from MAIN to IO thread for API operation
            // Update our data list with the new one from API
            val result = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                newsRepository?.data
                newsRepository.refresh()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

below my NewsRepository where I am fetching data and saving it to database

```
class NewsRepository(private val sportNewsApi: SportNewsInterface, private val sportNewsDao: SportNewsDao) {

        val data = sportNewsDao.getAllData()

        suspend fun refresh() {
            withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                val articles = sportNewsApi.getNewsAsync().body()?.articles
                if (articles != null) {
                    sportNewsDao.addAll(articles)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

below NewsDao.kt

```
@Dao
interface SportNewsDao {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM  Article")
    fun getAllData(): LiveData<List<Article>>

    @Insert
    suspend fun addAll(article: List<Article>)


    @Update
    suspend fun updateArticle(article: Article)

    @Delete
    suspend fun deleteArticle(article: Article)

}
```

below SportNewsDatabase.kt

```
@Database(entities = [Article::class], version = 1, exportSchema = false)
@TypeConverters(SourceTypeConverters::class)
abstract class SportNewsDatabase : RoomDatabase() {

    abstract fun sportNewsDao(): SportNewsDao

    companion object {
        private var instance: SportNewsDatabase? = null
        fun getInstance( context: Context): SportNewsDatabase? {
            if (instance == null) {
                synchronized(SportNewsDatabase::class.java) {
                    instance = Room.databaseBuilder(context.applicationContext, SportNewsDatabase::class.java, "article_database")
                        .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                        .build()
                }
            }
            return instance
        }
    }


}
```

I want to know where I am making mistake why app showing empty white screen

Comment: You're not getting access of `data` (LiveData) on `NewsRepository` from your ViewModel. Once you do that then you can observe it from your activity.

Comment: how can I give access to it Glenn Sandoval

Comment: Make a method that returns the call `sportNewsDao.getAllData()` so you can call that method from the ViewModel.

Comment: I am calling that already please check in NewsRepository

Comment: Glenn Sandoval  I already implement that method as you suggest correct if I am wrong

Comment: Do you need the LiveData on your Repo? If you don't then you better return the call instead of creating a val.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211354/discussion-between-sashabeliy-and-glenn-sandoval).